# Is there anything like outline view in VS?

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2010, resharper

[image: Eclipse's Outline view]

I come from Eclipse world and there we have this kind of outline view.

Is there something like this in VS2010? Maybe some plugin? I do have ReSharper.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Yes. It's provided by ReSharper.

Go to ReSharper → Windows → File Structure.